# Swift 4.1 Type of expression is ambiguous without context

Tags: swift, swift4

I have tried a few suggestion from other stack overflow questions with similar issues but they didn't work. My issue only happened when I updated to the latest Xcode 9.3 from Xcode 9.2.

This line of code is giving me:

> "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

```
data = try container.decodeIfPresent([Model].self, forKey: .data)
```

Below is how my class looks like:

```
class JSONResponse<Model>: Decodable
{
    public var data: [Model]?
    public var details: JSONResponseDetails?
    public var errors: [JSONError]?

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
{
    case details
    case data
    case errors
}

public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
{
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    details = try container.decodeIfPresent(JSONResponseDetails.self, forKey: .details)
    errors = try container.decodeIfPresent([JSONError].self, forKey: .errors)
    data = try container.decodeIfPresent([Model].self, forKey: .data)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic `Model` must conform to `Decodable`, too

```
class JSONResponse<Model : Decodable>: Decodable
```

Comment: Changing to Decodable, I have to change my wrapper to Decodable as well. This is how I used to access my wrapper, but with Decodable added to it, how would I access it now? Xcode didn't provide any indication to help. Thanks!


let wrapper = try JSONWrapper<Model>.decode(data: data)

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: Never mind with it, I got it working. Thank you for the help adding the Decodable resolve the issue.